# Stolen Mac - Help Finding Serial Number?

Tags: mac, serial-number

My apartment was broken into yesterday and my Mac (Mavericks) is gone. I'm trying to dig up the serial number for the police, but I'm having zero luck. Here's what I've done so far, to no avail:

- Checked Find iPhone through my iPhone and iCloud.com (didn't iCloud show the serial number at one time?)
- Checked https://supportprofile.apple.com/
- Searched my emails for one from Apple from purchase (found an email with an almost 3 year old Order Number and a Crucial email with some specs)
- Searched for the box my Mac came in

Here are some things I still have that may help:

- An external drive used for Time Machine
- My iPhone used the Mac for iTunes syncing
- Programs connected to the Internet, like Dropbox and TeamViewer

The police have been here already and I've contacted my renter's insurance. I have the Mac Locked and on Notify When Found. But I would really love that serial number. Any ideas I haven't thought of or found online?

Comment: On apples site- "If you still have the original packaging for your iMac, you can find the serial number on the barcode label that is affixed to the packaging."

Answer (score 8):

Someone stole my iPads last week and I didn't have the serial numbers. I found the serial numbers on [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com). Once, logged in, scroll down to Devices and click view details. You will need to answer your security questions, but any of your devices that are linked to Apple ID will be shown with their serial numbers. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you _*so*_ much. I can't fathom why the iCloud interface only shows the last five digits, when they're willing to give you all of them, anyway. I got my MacBook stolen recently and couldn't find the SN until reading this answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you synced it up to your mac it should be stored in your preferences plist.

```
/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iPod.plist
```

This file stores all the information about devices you connected to iTunes.  You can easily get to your user library by holding **Option(alt)** when you click **Go** on the top menu.

Comment: This is good info if my iPhone is stolen, but my Mac was the stolen item.

Comment: Yeah I don't think macs hold the serial number anywhere since its read directly from the motherboard itself using ioreg.  Did you register your mac?  If so you can use the site https://selfsolve.apple.com/GetAgreements.do

Comment: Nothing there...

Comment: I can confirm that I see my Mac, along with serial number at that site. You need to be logged in with your Apple ID before that link will show anything though.